# JPA Multiple Entity with Collection Query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have the following in SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM table2 t2, table1 t1 WHERE t1.id=1 AND t2.t1_id IN(1, 2);
```

How would I do that in JPA?

I tried:

```
SELECT t2 FROM Table2 t2, Table1 t1 WHERE t1.id = :t1_id AND t2.t1 IN (t1.t1Collection)
```

With pseudo classes:

```
Table1
  private int id;
  private Collection<Table1> t1Collection;

Table2
  private int t2;
  private Table1 t1_id;
```

But I get:

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the [`elements`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-expressions) keyword:

```
SELECT t2 FROM Table2 t2, Table1 t1 WHERE t1.id = :t1_id AND t2.t1 IN elements(t1.t1Collection)
```

Comment: Just a clarification: `IN elements` is a Hibernate-specific syntax.  The JPA corollary is `member of`: